# A correction mark to indicate a word order reversal

Tags: grammar, writing, calligraphy

The question comes from a popular ancient legend from "In Search of the Supernatural" (搜神記, 4 century CE) about a person asking for his lifespan extension.

Here's the whole of it:

> 管輅至平原，見顏超貌主夭亡。顏父乃求輅延命。輅曰：「子歸，覓清酒鹿脯一斤，卯日，刈麥地南大桑樹下，有二人圍位，次但酌酒置脯，飲盡更斟，以盡為度。若問汝，汝但拜之，勿言。必合有人救汝。」顏依言而往，果見二人圍碁，頻置脯，斟酒于前。其人貪戲，但飲酒食脯。不顧數巡，北邊坐者忽見顏在，叱曰：「何故在此？」顏惟拜之。南面坐者語曰：「適來飲他酒脯，寧無情乎？」北坐者曰：「文書已定。」南坐者曰：「借文書看之。」見超壽止可十九歲，乃取筆挑上語曰：「救汝至九十年活。」顏拜而回。管語顏曰：「大助子，且喜得增壽。北邊坐人是北斗，南邊坐人是南斗。南斗注生，北斗主死。凡人受胎，皆從南斗過北斗；所有祈求，皆向北斗。」

The point of interest is this piece:

> 見超壽止可十九歲，乃取筆挑上語曰：「救汝至九十年活。」

The Southern Dipper God did something (挑上) to "十九" turning it into "九十". I was wondering what exactly it was and the only satisfactory commentary I've found stated that he put a certain mark or nitpick (挑) above (上) the characters, signifying the character order reversal.

Since then I was trying to find any further reference to this orthographical practice and find out how that mark could look like. Any leads?

Answer (score 2):

i think that “挑上” is a specialised term in taoism, describing an action in writing charm paper (劃符)

上清天心正法

> 使眞炁吹之・發筆**挑上**・鬼字寫在内

靈寶無量度人上經大法

> 止念其玉諱爲呪・不計其數・次以一筆**挑上**・蓋其形・呪曰

上清靈寳大法

> 又念四字・毎一字四轉塗之・共一十六轉・剔筆上出・次以一筆**挑上**・蓋之・呪曰

so, the verse in 搜神記

> 乃取筆挑上・語曰・救汝至九十年活

read it as, the southern dipper deity took a pen, made a remark, and promised a life of 90 years, **verbally**

further, the northern dipper deity was the in-charge of death, that the southern dipper deity need his counterpart’s help, to finish the formalities in the office

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I remember it is called a Reverse order marking (逆序標記), "挑上" describes the action of "drawing a pen stroke" (on a surface)

This indicates 十九 is changed to 九十

[image]

Reverse order marking and insert word marking

[image]